# Reverse motor direction not working (just stops)

Tags: hvac, electric-motor

So I successfully purchased and installed an Mars 10204 motor and installed it in my condenser unit outside (the previous GE motor died a horrible death after years of service).

Only problem is it is running in reverse.  There are 4 wires that come out of the side, that are joined in pairs through knife blade connectors (two males and two females).  Brown to orange, and blue to yellow.

When I remove the connections and connect each male to the other female, the fan just doesn't work.

Suggestions?  Is it possible I need to join male-male and female-female?  Ugh.  I wouldn't think so and hate having to install new connectors.

Comment: There's a wiring diagram printed on the side of the motor, that show how to wire it for both clockwise and anticlockwise rotation.